# How to distinct records on entity name while "casing"/looking to different conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to a performing way to retrieve in once a overview of companies having 4 conditions per MONTH by looking to file and some other objects. ;

- submitted a file or not by 
  `when date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "main$nomarketscansubmission".jan = true  then 'ValidNoSubmission'`
- has submitted a file, WITHOUT dropouts and in status 'Corresponds_with_account_note' by 
  `WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=false and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Corresponds_with_account_note'  THEN 'Complete'`
- has submitted a file, WITHOUT dropouts and in status ''Does_not_correspond_with_account_note' by 
  `'WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=false and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Does_not_correspond_with_account_note'  then 'Incomplete''`
- has submitted a file, with dropouts and in status ''Does_not_correspond_with_account_note' by 
  `'WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=true and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Does_not_correspond_with_account_note'  then 'Incomplete''`
- other state by 
  `ELSE 'noSubmission`

So with that, I created, may be not the best one the following query;

```
SELECT 
    "main$debtor".companyname, 
    date_part('MONTH',todate),
    to_char(todate, 'Month'),
    "main$nomarketscansubmission".jan as FileUploadedInJAN,
    "main$nomarketscansubmission".feb as FileUploadedInFEB,
    "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout as HasBlockingDropout,
    "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote,


    CASE  
        when date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "main$nomarketscansubmission".jan = true  then 'ValidNoSubmission' 
        WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=false and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Corresponds_with_account_note'  THEN 'Complete' 
        WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=false and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Does_not_correspond_with_account_note'  then 'Incomplete' 
        WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 1 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=true and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Does_not_correspond_with_account_note'  then 'Incomplete'       
        ELSE 'noSubmission'  
     END AS FinalStatusJAN,

     CASE  
        when date_part('MONTH',todate) = 2 and "main$nomarketscansubmission".jan = true  then 'ValidNoSubmission' 
        WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 2 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=false and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Corresponds_with_account_note'  THEN 'Complete' 
        WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 2 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=false and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Does_not_correspond_with_account_note'  then 'Incomplete' 
        WHEN date_part('MONTH',todate) = 2 and "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout=true and "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote='Does_not_correspond_with_account_note'  then 'Incomplete'       
        ELSE 'noSubmission'    
     END AS FinalStatusFEB


FROM 
    "processing$movementapproval"
inner join
    "processing$movementapproval_debtor" on "processing$movementapproval".id="processing$movementapproval_debtor"."processing$movementapprovalid"
inner join 
    "main$debtor" on "processing$movementapproval_debtor"."main$debtorid"="main$debtor".id 
inner join
    "main$nomarketscansubmission_debtor" on "main$debtor".id = "main$nomarketscansubmission_debtor"."main$debtorid"
inner join
    "main$nomarketscansubmission" on "main$nomarketscansubmission_debtor"."main$nomarketscansubmissionid" = "main$nomarketscansubmission_debtor"."main$nomarketscansubmissionid"
where 
    date_part('YEAR',todate) = 2019 and "main$debtor".companyname ='Amstel Lloyd Assuradeuren B.V.'
group by
    "main$debtor".companyname,
    "processing$movementapproval".todate, 
    "processing$movementapproval".hasblockingdropout, 
    "processing$movementapproval".StatusAccountNote,
    "main$nomarketscansubmission".jan,
    "main$nomarketscansubmission".feb
order by 
    1,
    "main$debtor".companyname, 
    date_part('month',todate) asc
```

(cutted to just february but you got the idea that month specific select, case, group by recurring)

Now I got for each month a record ;

```
|companyname  |date_part                |to_char    |fileuploadedinjan|fileuploadedinfeb|hasblockingdropout|statusaccountnote                    |finalstatusjan    |finalstatusfeb 
|-------------|-------------------------|-----------|-----------------|-----------------|------------------|-------------------------------------|------------------|---------------
|A            |4                        |April      |true             |false            |true              |Corresponds_with_account_note        |noSubmission      |noSubmission 
|A            |5                        |May        |true             |false            |true              |Corresponds_with_account_note        |noSubmission      |noSubmission 
|A            |6                        |June       |true             |false            |true              |No_account_note_yet                  |noSubmission      |noSubmission 
|A            |7                        |July       |true             |false            |true              |No_account_note_yet                  |noSubmission      |noSubmission
```

How can I query on a performing way per company, per month to the 5 conditions?

Could not figure it out by distincting it or putting a subquery.